# How do I toggle the windscreen wipers on and off?

Tags: gran-turismo-5

So I was steadily racing along in my Lotus Elise, approaching a corner, when I was slightly distracted.

Needless to say, this distraction ended with me going sideways across the gravel, and in a blind panic to halt my car before I was three miles off the track, I ended up button mashing to find the handbrake.

While this was occurring, I must have pressed something else by accident, since the windscreen wipers turned on. When back on track I continued to button mash but could not find the button I pressed to turn them off again, nor could I turn them on in a future race.

What button toggles the operation of the windscreen wipers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To toggle the wipers, press <kbd>R3</kbd> (push the right analog stick in).

Comment: To clarify for anyone that doesn't know, that means push the right analog stick in.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out all the controls by going to game settings and seeing what buttons are assigned to what. You can also change them.